# Compiling C++/CX on the command line

Tags: visual-c++, command-line, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2015, c++-cx

I get the linker error `fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'platform.winmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable` when I try to compile a C++/CX program on the command line.

The error is the same after I followed the instructions on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn769142.aspx (to summarize: run `cl /ZW /EHsc source.cpp` from the *Developer Command Prompt for VS2015*)

I also tried running `vcvarsall.bat x86 store` from the *Developer Command Prompt for VS2015* but I still get the same error (the same error also happens when running `vcvarsall.bat x86 store` from a plain command prompt).

Comment: Hmm, that's not a linker error.  Just let the "visual" in VS tell you how to do this. Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity = Detailed.  Now you can see how the IDE does it, the build trace shows you how it uses required /FU option.  Unintentionally descriptive of the wisdom of doing this by hand btw, use msbuild.exe instead.

Comment: @HansPassant yes you are correct that is not a linker error, my bad. Switching to msbuild is not a solution for me as I am trying to build boost and projects which use cmake.

Comment: @HansPassant after adding `/FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\store\references\platform.winmd"` I still get the same error :(

Comment: @HansPassant when I copy paste all the options I get this `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vccorlib.h(348): error C3940: 'EventRegistrationToken': identifier not found - possible mismatch between compiler and library versions. Please ensure vccorlib.h/.lib, vccorlib120.dll and c1xx.dll match
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vccorlib.h(348): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation`

Comment: Pretty unlikely you actually copy/pasted all the options.  It lives in Windows.winmd, another /FU you saw and always required.

Comment: it kind of works now, care to write it up as an answer so that I can approve it?

Comment: You can't reasonably expect me to write it up after I tried so hard to talk you out of it.  Feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: @HansPassant sure I will write my own answer. Just out of curiousity, can you recommend a better way for me, for example in order to port boost to winrt (which is what I need this for)?

Comment: @HansPassant I see your point. Right now I am trying to get Boost.Log to compile for store. However Boost.Log uses Boost.Asio which has some things implemented using C++/CX, the same goes for Boost.Random for example.

Comment: You just don't build Boost with /ZW in effect.  To get it to stop using some of the *verboten* winapi functions that are not allowed in the sandbox check [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/07/18/using-boost-libraries-in-windows-store-and-phone-applications.aspx).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91393/discussion-between-mauve-and-hans-passant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UPDATE: Apparently this bug has been fixed in VS2015 Update 1, I have not been able to test myself yet though.

As it turns out some command line parameters are missing from the documentation mentioned in the question, here is the full command line required to compile a small program:

```
cl /ZW
   /ZW:nostdlib
   /D WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP
   /D __WRL_NO_DEFAULT_LIB__
   /Gm-
   /EHsc
   /MDd
   /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\store\references\platform.winmd"
   /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd"
   /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd"
   smurf.cpp
   /link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Where `smurf.cpp` contains:

```
using namespace Platform;

int main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ args)
{
    Platform::Details::Console::WriteLine("This is a C++/CX program.");
}
```

Will successfully print:

```
C:\Users\Mikael>smurf.exe
This is a C++/CX program.
```

Comment: As I've explained on the Boost mailing list, it seems VS 2015 .bat scripts are broken. In VS 2013 you did not have to add library paths explicitly.

Comment: This is the email @VladimirPrus is talking about (there may be others): http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2015/09/225609.php