# could not find assembly 'platform.winmd' when building Boost 1_60 using VS 2015

Tags: boost, build, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build the Boost libraries with windows-api=store for Visual Studio 2015 but I'm getting the following error: `could not find assembly 'platform.winmd'`.

Here's my build statement:

```
.\b2 --build-dir=bld  link=shared runtime-link=shared threading=multi address-model=64 --toolset=msvc-14.0 windows-api=store
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945500/compiling-c-cx-on-the-command-line) mentions that Update 1 for Visual Studio 2015 might fix it but I'm still seeing these errors.

I've tried calling vcvarsall.bat with amd64 store but no luck.

Has anyone been able to build Boost v1_60 with VS 2015 Update 1 with windows-api=store?